# Inversion of Control and IoC Containers

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I understand the whole concept behind inversion of control, but struggle to figure out where an IoC container comes in and how it may help.

Here's an example. Let's say we have the following interfaces ...

```
public interface IWarrior
{
    string Name { get; }
    IWeapon Weapon { get; }
    void EquipWeapon(IWeapon weapon);
    void Attack(ITarget target);
    void DoVictoryDance();
}

public interface IWeapon
{
    int AttackPower { get; }
}

public interface ITarget
{
    int Health { get; }
    int ArmorValue { get; }
    int ReceiveAttack(int damage);
}
```

A IWarrior base class ...

```
public abstract class BaseWarrior : IWarrior
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    protected BaseWarrior(string name, IWeapon weapon)
    {
        Name = name;
        Weapon = weapon;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public IWeapon Weapon { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Attack(ITarget target)
    {
        var attackValue = Random.Next(0, Weapon.AttackPower + 1);

        var damageDone = target.ReceiveAttack(attackValue);

        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} did {damageDone} to {target.GetType().Name}");

        if (target.Health <= 0)
            DoVictoryDance();
    }

    public virtual void EquipWeapon(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        Weapon = weapon;
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} equips {weapon.GetType().Name}");
    }

    public abstract void DoVictoryDance();
}
```

The concrete warriors types ...

```
    public class Samurai : BaseWarrior
{
    public Samurai(string name, IWeapon weapon) : base(name, weapon)
    {
    }

    public override void DoVictoryDance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} dances on top of the corpses of his foes.");
    }
}

public class ChuckNorris : BaseWarrior
{
    public ChuckNorris() : base("Chuck Norris", null)
    {
    }

    public override void Attack(ITarget target)
    {
        var targetName = target.GetType().Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"Chuck Norris stares at {targetName}. {targetName} collapses on the floor, dead. {targetName} never saw Chuck Norris.");

        DoVictoryDance();
    }

    public override void EquipWeapon(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chuck Norris needs no weapons you fool!");
    }

    public override void DoVictoryDance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chuck Norris doesn't dance. He stares at you until you do it for him.");
    }
}
```

The following weapons...

```
public class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public int AttackPower => 10;
}

public class CrossBow : IWeapon
{
    public int AttackPower => 15;
}
```

And finally a basic enemy:

```
public class Bear : ITarget
{
    public int Health { get; private set; } = 100;
    public int ArmorValue => 2;
    public int ReceiveAttack(int damage)
    {
        var damageTaken = damage - ArmorValue;

        if (damageTaken > 0)
            Health -= damageTaken;

        return damageTaken;
    }
}
```

It's clear to me what inversion of control here is. My main class needs not know the concrete type of `IWarrior`, `IWarrior` never knows the concrete type of `IWeapon` or `ITarget`.

So this allows me to do something like ...

```
ITarget target = new Bear();
IWarrior warrior = new ChuckNorris();
warrior.Attack(target);
```

or ...

```
ITarget target = new Bear()
IWarrior warrior = new Samurai("Ben", new Sword());
warrior.Attack(target);
```

And I can see how it would be easier to have a container that just stores my objects so I don't "lose track of them" (don't want a lot of swords or weapons flying around for example, also those could be singletons).

Examples I've seen of IoC containers show something similar to this:

```
IocContainer container = new IocContainer();
container.Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>();
container.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
container.Bind<ITarget>().To<Bear>();
```

and then doing something like...

```
ITarget target = container.Get<ITarget>();
IWarrior warrior = container.Get<IWarrior>();
warrior.Attack(target);
```

But now I'm basically saying that my `IWarrior` is always a `Samurai`, that my `IWeapon` is always a `Sword` and that my `ITarget` is always a `Bear`.

That's not really what I wanted! I want to be able to create different `IWarrior` types with different `IWeapon` combinations and attacking a multitude of `ITargets`!

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something basic about how an IoC container works, but I have seen a few videos about them (using multiple libraries) and they all appear to basically say *when I want "something" implementing interface XX, find in your container an object of concrete type YY. If you don't have one there yet, create one, save it, and send it back to me.*

Can someone explain what the advantages of an IoC container are, give real examples of how it works and how one can preserve choice (by not limiting a `IWarrior` to `Samurai` as above for example)?

Comment: I think your scenario is a bad example as you would use IoC mainly for dependency injection and then rather for services and not business objects. The idea is that you have class which has dependencies on other classes and these have further dependencies. Without IoC you would always need to know which concrete implementation to use and it would be difficult to replace an implementation by another without changing every usage. With IoC you have a central place we’re you register your implementations and you just state in constructor what interfaces you want but rarely manually by using Get.

Comment: @ckuri I think that as a DI/IoC example it's a good one (bearing in mind that IoC is a very loose term). As a candidate for an IoC container it might not be, but then again since I'm having trouble understanding what exactly an IoC container facilitates with that would be expected. Can you provide a explanation (with code included) of an appropriate example where an IoC container would help and why my example is a bad example? If my questions are answered I'll mark the answer...

Comment: @cogumel0 I faced the same issues and this reading helps me : [How do I pick a service implementation by context?](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#how-do-i-pick-a-service-implementation-by-context) Basically some IoC container can let you choose which component is used in different instance